# Custom C# attribute to disable methods in controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, attributes

I have an asp. Net Core WebAPI application, I have created a generic custom base controller class that already provides CRUD operations (GetAll, GetById, Insert, Update and Delete) for any controller that's being inherited from.

In some of my controllers, I have to disable some methods. Of course I could use the [nonaction] attribute to do so.

Is it possible to implement an attribute and apply it on my controller to disable a series on methods?

Here is a bit of my code:

```cs
public interface IBaseService<T> where T : DomainObject {
    Task<PagedResultViewModel<T>> GetAllAsync(BaseRequestViewModel request);
    Task<SingleResultViewModel<T>> GetByIdAsync(int id);
    Task<SingleResultViewModel<T>> InsertAsync(T entity);
    Task<SingleResultViewModel<T>> UpdateAsync(T entity);
    Task<SingleResultViewModel<T>> DeleteAsync(int id);
}
```

and my custom base controller is like this:

```cs
public class ProcessMiningControllerBase<T> : ControllerBase where T : DomainObject
{
    private readonly IBaseService<T> _baseService;

    public ProcessMiningControllerBase(IBaseService<T> baseService)
    {
        _baseService = baseService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual async Task<PagedResultViewModel<T>> GetAllAsync(BaseRequestViewModel request)
    {
        return await _baseService.GetAllAsync(request);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public virtual async Task<SingleResultViewModel<T>> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _baseService.GetByIdAsync(id);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual async Task<SingleResultViewModel<T>> InsertAsync(T entity)
    {
        return await _baseService.InsertAsync(entity);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public virtual async Task<SingleResultViewModel<T>> UpdateAsync(T entity)
    {
        return await _baseService.UpdateAsync(entity);
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public virtual async Task<SingleResultViewModel<T>> DeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _baseService.DeleteAsync(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to extract those CRUDs into a repository Service or something? In my opinion this is nothing belonging to the controller. Is there any reason you do it this way?

Comment: I added a bit of my code for clarification

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Ah okay, and now you want to use this base Controller all over the place, where then afterwards on usage you want to decide which http methods are really unlocked for the implemented Controller, is this right?

Comment: that's right! exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys by the way!
I actually found the right implementation

1. Define a custom attribute

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
   public class DisableBaseOperationsAttribute : Attribute
   {

   }
   ```
2. Then I implemented the IControllerModelConvention interface like below:

```
public class ProcessMiningControllerModelConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    private List<string> baseOperations;
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        baseOperations = new List<string>()
        {
            "GetAll",
            "GetById",
            "Insert",
            "Update",
            "Delete",
        };
        bool disableCrud = controller.Attributes.Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(DisableBaseOperationsAttribute));
        if (disableCrud)
        {
            var crudActions = controller.Actions.Where(a => baseOperations.Contains(a.ActionName));
            foreach (var action in crudActions)
            {
                action.ApiExplorer.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

3. And finally config AddControllers like:

   ```
   builder.Services.AddControllers(s => s.Conventions.Add(new ProcessMiningControllerModelConvention()));
   ```
4. Now you could easily use the attribute on your controller to disable base operations

Answer (score 1):

You can disable a controller with its action in four steps:

1- Create an action filter attribute to make the controller always return 404 NOT Found like the code below:

```
    public class DisableControllerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new NotFoundObjectResult(null);
    }
}
```

2- Register the filter in the application Program.cs like this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers((c) => c.Filters.Add<DisableControllerAttribute>());
```

3- Decorate the controller with the action filter you have created:

```
[DisableController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
```

4- This step is optional. If you want to hide the controller from Swagger page also add the following attribute to the controller

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```